# How to use html_safe in a secure manner?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, html-safe

I was wondering when it is safe to use `html_safe` and when not. I read that you don't want to do this if the code may contain user content. What does this mean in practice?

```
flash[:danger]="Dear #{@user.username} <br> please take a look #{view_context.link_to('here', some_path)}" <br> Your organization #{@user.organizationname} bla bla"
```

For example, for a flash message such as this one, will need `html_safe` to display correctly, but it also contains in this case `username` and `organizationname` which is content entered by the user. Is it then still safe to use `html_safe`...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you inject user content into strings you render with html_safe you have to make sure all the injected content is `sanitized`

```
flash[:danger]="Dear #{ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize @user.username} <br> please take a look #{view_context.link_to('here', some_path)}" <br> Your organization #{ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize @user.organizationname} bla bla"
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html

Comment: How is this with regard to shared error messages? I have: `<% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>` `<li><%= msg.html_safe %></li>` `<% end %>`. Is it better to change this to: `<%= sanitize msg.html_safe %>` or `<%= msg %>`? To the best of my knowledge, I only have plain text custom error messages, but you never know given the gems used... What would you say is best-practice for shared error messages?

Comment: I think it is common and good practice to have plain text only in active record error messages. I've never seen anyone doing `html_safe` on them. So I would definitely omit the html_safe for the extra security until you really need it. I don't think any reasonable gem provider does or should place HTML in active record error messages.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, it is not, malevolent user could enter some harmful js code as his `organizationname`, and this code would than become part of your app - you don't want this. This attack is known as Cross-site scripting (XSS), and you can read about it i.e. here:
http://www.jasonwieringa.com/Learning-About-XSS-Attacks-in-Rails/

As axel pointed, you should call `sanitize` on every user input that you want to mark as `html_safe` what it does is replacing all html special characters as entities, so any unwanted markup or js code will not be interpreted by user browser.